# .Net equivalent of the vb6 Tab control paradigm

Tags: .net, forms, vb6

My co-workers are used to using tab controls with the tab height set to zero in vb6 to allow multiple panels overlayed on one form and now want to do the same in .Net. Unfortunately they've been confused by the fact that there are some extra hoops you have to jump though to make it work the same way.

A bit of judicious googling solved the problem, but VB.net just doesn't seem geared towards this method of managing space on a form. Does anyone have any advice on the best way of arranging what used to be multiple layers of panels within one tab control in .net? (or is still widely accepted as a good way of doing things?)

Comment: Hard to guess what you googled.  Displaying a tab control without tabs isn't hard to do.

Comment: Use a TabControl?  Create a wizard?  Use menu-bars or context menus or scroll-bars or a grid/list/TreeView... really, it depends on what you're trying to do.  What information are you trying to display?  What information should be grouped together, and what should be separated?  What does the user do with this information?  These are the important questions to ask (and once you figure out the answers, [ui.stackexchange.com](http://ui.stackexchange.com) would be a good place to ask more specific UI questions)

Comment: Please add a screenshot showing what you are describing (in vb6).

Comment: Yes, it took me five minutes to look it up, for some reason the first few obvious ways of doing it didn't work, the combination of settings you need isn't immediately obvious. My training's in physics rather than form design, I was hoping I wouldn't have to touch it but it looks like I don't have a choice.

Comment: It sounds like the question I've asked is far too general to be much use, it looks like I'll have to do some reading before I try anything else. Thanks Danny for the excellent comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make different user controls so to separate logic and decouple things if and as much as possible then in a tab control you display those user controls in the pages. But if you are making kind of wizard like interface there are specific and better approaches to use.

Answer (score 1):

As Davide said, you can use different controls and load and unload via code.

You can also use layout panels with similar results, although that is more difficult to use (in the GUI editor.)

.Net also has a tab control which can provide multiple pages of controls on the same form, but I've never tried it without the tabs.  I have, in the past, disabled the tabs which do not have input focus, but that sort of defeats the purpose of tab controls.

I would tend to make a separate form for each user screen.  It's cleaner, easier, and more extensible.  Maintain the program state in a class and have the class invoke the forms.

Comment: That was my first response, thanks for letting me know I'm not mad.